# confused ,why Object[] objs (type of objs[i] is int[]) cant cast into int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting

list.toArray() returns Object[] and it contains only int[].
So i thought i can cast it directly into int[][].
But actually i was wrong,it will lead to a cast exception.

```
list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);
```

it's ok this way,but i'm still confused.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
//some code

//cast exception
return (int[][])list.toArray();
//this way is ok
return list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);
```

Why does it throw that exception?

Comment: Because an `Object[]` is not an `int[][]`, it just is not, not in this case and even less so in general. Inspect the source of the two `toArray` implementations.

Comment: You can't do it with a list of Strings, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here:

```
//cast exception
return (int[][])list.toArray();
```

Due to type erasure, this one creates an actual array of **Object**. An array of Objects is **not** an array of int arrays, thus you can't cast it. A box for eggs doesn't turn into a bottle for milk just because you scream "behold, become a bottle" at it.

To make that really clear: the above call doesn't know the exact type to use, so it has to resort to that basic default `Object[]`. And because `int[]` is of type Object, that list method can then store these arrays into the result array. An array of objects, and each object is an array of int.

But here:

```
return list.toArray(new int[list.size()][]);
```

You explicitly say that the array returned should be of type `int[][]`. Thus, at runtime, the body of that method knows that it should return that 
type.

And just for the record: you might prefer

```
return list.toArray(new int[0][]);
```

Providing an "already sized" array is a relict from earlier times, in general, in 2019, you prefer passing an empty array.

Comment: Next to being a great and clear answer, *A box for eggs doesn't turn into a bottle for milk just because you scream at it* +1

Comment: Can you elaborate on your assertion that "An array of Objects is not an array of int arrays"? Why not? We are often told that a Java array is an Object. So why isn't an array of arrays also an array of Objects?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException a `String` is not an `Integer` is it? The same goes for different arrays

Comment: @DodgyCodeException It works this way: a `int[][]` is of type Object!. But the two types `Object[]` and `int[][]` are in no way related. And yes, `Object[]` is also of type Object.

Comment: My thinking goes like this. The `Object[]` array returned is an array of Objects. You can legally do `Object[] objArr = list.toArray(); int[] intArr = (int[]) objArr[0];` You won't get a cast exception. It will work. Which proves that it really is an array of int arrays. So if each element of the array can be cast to `int[]` why can't the whole array be cast to `int[][]`? @Lino it's not the same as String vs Integer.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Again, the types `Object[]` and `int[]` are **not** related at all. See the update I made to the answer. `int[]` has type Object, thus an array of Object can hold `int[]` entries. It could also hold one `int[]`, then a String, then an Integer, then null, and then an array of MilkBottles. Because anything in Java, in the end is an Object. But the array type is fixed, and as said three times: the two types array of Object and array of int are **not** related or equal or "parent" and "child".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You are talking about that. Because as explained: the first method does **not** know that the element type is `int[][]`. The List type is `List<int[]>` thus the elements in the list are array-of-int. And you can easily assign an array-of-int into slots of array-of-object.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException maybe [this](https://ideone.com/fzmghs) does help in understanding?

Comment: @Eugene This is very displeasing... but I am still amused